(node:472) [DEP0170] DeprecationWarning
(node:472) [DEP0170] DeprecationWarning: The URL mongodb://gmpsankalpa:******4@ac-ubhbutz-shard-00-01.qrgbii1.mongodb.net:27017,ac-ubhbutz-shard-00-02.qrgbii1.mongodb.net:27017,ac-ubhbutz-shard-00-00.qrgbii1.mongodb.net:27017/test?authSource=admin&replicaSet=atlas-11yn0k-shard-0&retryWrites=true&w=majority&ssl=true is invalid. Future versions of Node.js will throw an error. (Use node --trace-deprecation ... to show where the warning was created)
how to fix this warning message?
enter image description here

You should probably change your password, now that it’s public.

Have a look at Atlas UI to see correct connection string

Node version and mongoose version compatibility mismatch. Update your mongoose version to the latest currently V8 and ensure you are running Node LTS V20.  For best practice also use the Atlas connection string format in @WernfriedDomscheit answer.

The connection string must be like this:
"mongodb+srv://gmpsankalpa:*******@ac-ubhbutz.qrgbii1.mongodb.net"

However, in general your connection string should be valid. But without node --trace-deprecation as advised in the error message I can just guess.
Maybe ssl=true is not valid. Use tls=true instead.
retryWrites=true is also useless, MongoDB drivers retry transaction commit and abort operations regardless of the value of retryWrites.
